# Finding an element that has : specific attribute and a child with specific text

Tags: xpath, watir-webdriver

For the fallowing sample of code , i need to check if a tr ,with type="a" and that has a td with text "3" as a child ,exists:

```
<table>
    <tr type="a">
     <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr type="b">
     <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr type="a">
     <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Tried this :

```
    b.tr( :xpath =>"//tr[@type='a']").td( :text =>'3').exists?
```

but it doesnt work ( the `xpath` expression returns only the first tr of the 2 existing).

Any ideas ?
Is there an xpath expression that will return true if the `tr` I need exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, this can also be done without xpath:

```
b.trs.count{ |tr|
  tr.attribute_value('type') == 'a' and tr.td(:text, '3').present? 
} > 0
```

A little bit more verbose, but I think it is easier to read than xpaths.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
boolean(/*/tr[@type='a']/td[. = 3])
```

This XPath expression evaluates to `true()` exactly when there exists a `td` whose string value is equal to the number 3, and that has parent `tr` the string value of whose `type` attribute is "a", and which (the `tr`) is a child of the top element of the XML document.

Otherwise the XPath expression evaluates to `false()`

Answer (score 0):

```
b.tr(:xpath =>"//tr[@type='a']", :index => 1).td(:text =>'3').exists?
```

or

```
b.tr(:xpath =>"(//tr[@type='a'])[2]").td(:text =>'3').exists?
```

Comment: Not sure why you are using an index..?
That was just an example of a code , i dont know for sure that what im looking for will have index 2

Answer (score 0):

Well am not sure if this helps but this code returns a count of how many elements the xpath expression returns , so you can check if the count is 0 then no matches otherwise it would return the number of matches :

```
var doc = document.evaluate("//table/tbody/tr[@type='a']/td[text()=1]",document,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
doc.snapshotLength
```

or

```
var doc = document.evaluate("//table[@id='tableId']/tbody/tr[@type='a']/td[text()=1]",document,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
doc.snapshotLength
```

if you have an id for your table.

Hope this helps in any way.